# SignalR 2.2.0: client cannot call hub, hub doesn't get called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Everything was working and now it's not :) I keep looking through my source control, but I can't figure out what went wrong. I'm not getting errors and I'm having trouble finding out what's going wrong when debugging. The client command to call the hub gets called, but the hub never gets called. No idea why.

```
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

/signalR/hubs script does get generated.

It used to work with the following packages that I currently have installed using NuGet(I've tried reinstalling them)

```
Microsoft ASP.NET SignalR Core Components
Microsoft ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Client
Microsoft ASP.NET SignalR System.Web
Microsoft ASP.NET SignalR
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
Microsft.Owin.Security
Microsoft.Owin
OWIN
```

UpdateInstallProgress(string installID) never gets called :(

```
namespace RealtimeInstaller.Hubs
{
    public class UpdateInstallHub : Hub
    {
        public void UpdateInstall()
        {
            Clients.All.updateInstall();
        }

        public void UpdateInstallProgess(string installID)
        {
            Clients.All.updateInstallProgess(installID);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is where the client calls the server in JS. This does get called, but then the hub never gets called!

```
connection.server.updateInstallProgess(@ViewBag.installID);
```

Don't worry about what's in the body, below is the client side JS code that never gets called! This is because the hub never gets called to call this client side code.

```
    var connection = $.connection.updateInstallHub;  

    connection.client.updateInstallProgess = function (installID) {
        //code that never gets called :(
    };
```

Below is Startup.cs

```
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();       //mapping the SignalR hubs to the http routes
        }
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the hub get called? I suspect it has something to do with my packages/references, but I'm not sure how to fix it anymore than just reinstalling the packages I mentioned earlier. Any ideas at all will be appreciated!

Comment: Turn on logging to see what's going on. You did not show the client code - for instance - I don't see that you even start the connection.

Comment: Turn on logging like this?

        connection.logging = true;

Can you give me the example of what the client code to "start the connection" would look like?

Thank you for your response

Comment: Here is a great tutorial http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

Comment: Thank you Pawel, I'll give it another look. I guess I may have accidentally changed something, because I had it working before.

Comment: Pawel, you were right. I lost         $.connection.hub.start().done(function () ...... in a merge.

I wish you posted an answer so I could give you rep+.
If you answer the question I will :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you js code you showed you don't seem to be starting the connection.